# Symfony .htaccess redirect subdomain to route with params

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

I have a subdomain `xxx.yyy.fr` configured with apache2 to the folder `/var/www/my_symfony_project/web/`

By default, symfony redirect all others queries to `/app.php` (with the .htaccess in /web directory) :

```
# Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
```

So, `xxx.yyy.fr` is redirected to `xxx.yyy.fr/app.php/`

I have a route like : `xxx.yyy.fr/app.php/my_route/{optional_param}`, with a controller and a view.

My question is : How can I rewrite this url for, when I go to `xxx.yyy.fr/{optional_param}` is like I go to the full url `xxx.yyy.fr/app.php/my_route/{optional_param}` ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Do you only have one route?

Otherwise it will always redirect to the route you set up .

I think you need something like this. And one thing. If you redirect everything to a single url, your images/, js/, css/ files will not work. They will also redirect.

You can try something like this. This is what im currently using.

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# Explicitly disable rewriting for front controllers
RewriteRule ^/web/app.php/your_route - [L]

# Fix the bundles folder
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ /web/css/$1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ /web/js/$1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^bundles/(.*)$ /web/bundles/$1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fonts/(.*)$ /web/fonts/$1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ /web/images/$1  [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Change below before deploying to production
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/app.php/your_route [QSA,L]
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/app_dev.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

You do not need the /web part because you are already redirecting to /var/www/my_symfony_project/web/

Hope this helps